# Can there be local properties within a dependency block?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I'm developing a client-program, that connects to a huge vendor-provided application.

The application offers client API, which uses numerous JARs -- both from the application vendor and the open-source ones, which the vendor are using too. All of these JARs are in a single directory -- and I want to use *that* (instead of downloading them from the various sites) to save both diskspace and RAM, both at build- and at runtime.

So I use a `<scope>system</scope>` and provide the `<systemPath>` for each JAR:

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${foo.jars}/log4j-1.2.17.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
```

I then provide the property's value on `mvn`'s command-line: `-Dfoo.jars=/path/to/application/jar`. This works, but it bothers me, that the name and the version of each must be specified in two places: in the `<artifactId>` or `<version>` first, and then again in the `systemPath`.

Is there, perhaps, some way to parametrize it further? For example:

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${foo.jars}/${this.artifactId}-${this.version}.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
```

Or, maybe, I can somehow tell Maven to use the same "formula" for all `<systemPath>`-entries automatically -- and not have to spell each one out?

Comment: No, and using systemPath is usually considered bad practise.

Comment: Have you considered that "downloading them from the various sites" happens just the first time? Maven uses a local cache.

Comment: @Pino, most of the JARs I need are from the vendor and wouldn't be found in any JAR-repository _anyway_. The rest are exactly of the versions desired by the vendor's software, so there is no benefit to have them downloaded from a repository either.

Comment: If your company has a private Maven repo you could load these libraries there and avoid the `system` scope; otherwise, with these constraints, Maven is probably not the best choice: you could consider using Ant.

Comment: I would suggest to use a repository manager on the company site and consume from there... the parts which are in the repository manager can be controle very. good...

Comment: Why, @khmarbaise? What would setting such a thing up -- a considerable one-time cost plus ongoing maintenance -- buy me?